# Git LFS: Error due to filter-process when changing branches with new LFS file

Tags: git, terminal, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

After 3 hours of trying I can't understand why I get this error when I'm trying to go to a different branch where it was newly added an lfs file.

Errors logged to C:\Users\hp\cs-for-the-humanities-watermarks-18b.git\lfs\logs\20230602T224504.955467.log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: database/db.pkl: smudge filter lfs failed

Basically this is the error
Thx!

I've tried to use what other people said, but it was useless.
'''
git-lfs/3.0.2 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.17.2)
git version 2.35.1.windows.2

```
$ git-lfs.exe filter-process
Error downloading object: database/db.pkl (c05e62d): Smudge error: Error downloading database/db.pkl (c05e62d87b0303ddc10132e50a2d4db5d47d7fee0470e18da7d829e2d26f46fb): batch request: ssh: connect to host gitlab.ewi.tudelft.nl port 22: Connection timed out: exit status 255

exit status 255
ssh: connect to host gitlab.ewi.tudelft.nl port 22: Connection timed out
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/errors.newWrappedError
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:225
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/errors.Wrap
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/errors.go:74
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/lfshttp.(*Client).sshResolveWithRetries
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfshttp/client.go:228
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/lfshttp.(*Client).NewRequest
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfshttp/client.go:124
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/lfsapi.(*Client).NewRequest
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfsapi/client.go:13
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/tq.(*tqClient).Batch
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/api.go:84
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/tq.Batch
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/api.go:43
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/tq.(*TransferQueue).enqueueAndCollectRetriesFor
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/transfer_queue.go:558
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/tq.(*TransferQueue).collectBatches.func1
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/transfer_queue.go:452
runtime.goexit
        go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
batch request
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/errors.newWrappedError
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:225
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/errors.Wrap
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/errors.go:74
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/tq.(*tqClient).Batch
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/api.go:86
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/tq.Batch
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/api.go:43
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/tq.(*TransferQueue).enqueueAndCollectRetriesFor
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/transfer_queue.go:558
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/tq.(*TransferQueue).collectBatches.func1
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/transfer_queue.go:452
runtime.goexit
        go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
Error downloading database/db.pkl (c05e62d87b0303ddc10132e50a2d4db5d47d7fee0470e18da7d829e2d26f46fb)
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/errors.newWrappedError
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:225
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/errors.Wrapf
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/errors.go:85
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/lfs.(*GitFilter).downloadFile
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfs/gitfilter_smudge.go:119
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/lfs.(*GitFilter).Smudge
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfs/gitfilter_smudge.go:78
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/commands.smudge
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/command_smudge.go:127
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/commands.filterCommand
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/command_filter_process.go:122
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.3/command.go:766
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.3/command.go:852
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.3/command.go:800
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/commands.Run
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/run.go:105
main.main
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/git-lfs.go:33
runtime.main
        go/src/runtime/proc.go:255
runtime.goexit
        go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
Smudge error
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/errors.newWrappedError
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:225
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/errors.NewSmudgeError
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:311
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/lfs.(*GitFilter).Smudge
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfs/gitfilter_smudge.go:87
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/commands.smudge
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/command_smudge.go:127
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/commands.filterCommand
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/command_filter_process.go:122
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.3/command.go:766
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.3/command.go:852
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.3/command.go:800
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/v3/commands.Run
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/run.go:105
main.main
        D:/a/git-lfs/git-lfs/git-lfs.go:33
runtime.main
        go/src/runtime/proc.go:255
runtime.goexit
        go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581

Current time in UTC:
2023-06-02 21:06:40

ENV:
LocalWorkingDir=C:\Users\hp\cs-for-the-humanities-watermarks-18b
LocalGitDir=C:\Users\hp\cs-for-the-humanities-watermarks-18b\.git
LocalGitStorageDir=C:\Users\hp\cs-for-the-humanities-watermarks-18b\.git
LocalMediaDir=C:\Users\hp\cs-for-the-humanities-watermarks-18b\.git\lfs\objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=C:\Users\hp\cs-for-the-humanities-watermarks-18b\.git\lfs\tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=8
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=C:\Users\hp\cs-for-the-humanities-watermarks-18b\.git\lfs
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file,ssh
UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file,ssh
GIT_ASKPASS=c:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\askpass.sh
GIT_EXEC_PATH=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
GIT_PREFIX=
```

'''

Comment: Can you run `git lfs logs last` and edit your question to include it as a code block?  That would help us figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I did. It's updated.

Answer (score 0):

Git LFS is designed to keep large files stored outside of the main Git storage and instead download them on demand from a remote file server.  This means that the space used for the repository is less significant.

In your case, Git LFS believes the file it needs to download is not present, and is trying to download it from the remote.  By default, the remote used is `origin`.  In this case, Git LFS is trying to connect over SSH because the remote is SSH, and the connection to the GitLab server is timing out.

If Git LFS cannot connect to the remote server, then it cannot download the object, and because Git will not complete the checkout until Git LFS returns a success or failure, your checkout is taking a long time.  If you want to use a different remote, then you can set `remote.lfsdefault` to a different location (e.g., `git config remote.lfsdefault REMOTE`) and it will use that remote instead.

Note that in some cases, Git LFS 3.0 and newer may make an SSH connection even if one is not needed due to [a bug which has been fixed and will be in the upcoming v3.4.0](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/pull/5309), which will likely be released in June 2023.  You can build your own version from the main branch in the meantime if this is a problem.